# Typescript debugging in VS not working for Aurelia JSPM set up

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, typescript1.4, aurelia

In trying to run the Aurelia demo app in Visual Studio (2013 update 4) using Typescript (v1.4), I am running into this dreaded error in TS files for views.

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

This set up is very similar to the original in that config.js is used with SystemJS.  I am running it in IIS express in IE 11.

If the Aurelia set up is changed to a one bundled JS file and requiredJS is used instead, the Typescript debugging works fine in VS. The breakpoint in this case shows up under '..in process "iexplore.exe"'.

The map files are generated in both cases.  All the debugging flags are set the same for the project.

Can anyone think of a way to fix the TYpescript debugging?

Debugging works fine in Chrome browser debugger for both versions.

Comment: "Debugging works fine in Chrome browser debugger for both versions." - just use chrome then ;-) (better debugging experience IMO anyway)

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get this to work, by adding the meta>scriptLoad setting to the config.js file.  This tells systemjs to load modules as script tags, rather than via eval().

```
meta : {
      "path/to/source/files": {scriptLoad: true}
       }
```

And now VS testing via IE loads scripts and hits breakpoints (in my case in the typescript files)

Answer (score -2):

Colin Dembovsky got it working and outlines the needed steps in his blog [here](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/aurelia--debugging-from-within-visual-studio).

The crux of it is because aurelia uses system.js to load it's modules by default.  You need to change it to use RequireJs instead. This takes a little work, but will give you what you are looking for.